# Getting data from poorly structured xml from sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

Hello I have a newbie question, apologies.

I have to work with a stupidly designed XML format 
that provides object attribute data as tags and where a 
tag value changes it implies an attribute.
Where an attribute is not provided eg. mammal, it implies
that the value is unknown.

Using the following as an example:
3rd level tag can be one of 20 different values.
4th level tag (mammal) can be one of several values and
may not exist.

How can I write an XQuery command to get beyond an 
unknown/missing tag?

select
       t.c.value('v[1]', 'varchar(100)') as animal
from @xml.nodes('/recs/rec/*/a1/*/ as t.c

```
declare @xml xml =
'
<recs>
        <rec>
        <a>
            <a1>
                <mammal>
                    <v>dog</v>
                </mammal>
            </a1>
        </a>
    </rec>
    <rec>
        <b>
            <a1>
                <mammal>
                    <v>cat</v>
                </mammal>
            </a1>
        </b>
    </rec>
    <rec>
        <b>
            <a1>
                <v>pig</v>
            </a1>
        </b>
    </rec>
</recs>'
```

Thanks

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  What does "get beyond" mean?  Do you mean you would like to select all fifth-level elements regardless of the name of their parent elements? `/*/*/*/*/*` will do that fine.

Comment: Yes, if the parent elements were consistently named I'd be able to write a query to get to them. My example only shows two names but there could be hundreds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all elements at the fifth level , use

```
/*/*/*/*/*
```

In the input you show, this will retrieve two `mammal` elements and a `pig`.  (You say `mammal` is at the fourth level; seem to be counting from zero; I'm counting from one.)  If you want their children, instead, add a `/*`.

If you want only fifth- or sixth-level elements within a particular context, you can of course replace the asterisks with something more restrictive:

```
/recs/rec/b/a1/*
```

for the fifth level, and

```
/recs/rec/b/a1/*/*
```

for the sixth.

Comment: How do I get the actual tag value ie. a1 or mammal?                         SELECT
Tab.Col.value('../v[1]', 'varchar(10)') as animal
,Tab.Col.value('v[1]', 'varchar(10)') as animal
FROM @xml.nodes('/recs/rec/*/a1/*') Tab(Col)

Comment: Read a tutorial on XPath; use `name()` to get the element name (which is what I assume you mean by 'the actual tag value', though it's not a 'value' in XDM).

Comment: @Shnugo - you may be right. Since the only thing the OP knows about the elements wanted is that they are at the *n*th level, I'm not seeing how to get them all without counting levels.  And my attention is focused on what appears on the surface to be OP's question about XQuery (or, strictly speaking, XPath).  If there are facilities within SQL Server's combination of SQL and XQuery that allow a better solution, fine with me.

Comment: Yeah, you may be right too, deleted my comment... Sorry for barking :-D After reading the question once again I think, that both our answers will not fully cover the needs. voted yours up

Comment: I just placed an update to my answer to cover the needs - hopefully

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to count the levels and combine the right count of `*`

Try this, it's using the *deep search* with `//`:

```
SELECT any_v.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TheTextWithinV
      ,any_v.value('local-name(..)','nvarchar(max)') AS TheNameOfTheParent
FROM @xml.nodes('//v') AS DeepSearch(any_v);
```

As you should be *as specific as possible* I'd suggest this in `.nodes()`

```
FROM @xml.nodes('/recs/rec//v') AS DeepSearch(any_v);
```

It will go down the path 'til `<rec>` then do the *deep search* 'til `<v>`.

As there is no other `text()` anywhere, you might even do this:

```
SELECT any_v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS FirstTextFound
FROM @xml.nodes('/recs/rec') AS DeepSearch(any_v);
```

### UPDATE One more approach

Try this

```
SELECT r.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS Level2
      ,r.value('local-name((./*)[1])','nvarchar(max)') AS Level3
      ,r.value('if(local-name((./*/*)[1])="v") then "" else local-name((./*/*)[1])','nvarchar(max)') AS Level4
      ,r.value('(.//v/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Level5
FROM  @xml.nodes('/recs/rec/*') AS A(r);
```

To get this

```
Level2  Level3  Level4  Level5
a       a1      mammal  dog
b       a1      mammal  cat
b       a1              pig
```